# Does this sum involving Champernowne's constants ever converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} C_n$, where $C_n$ is the base-$n$ [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant).
I tried computing it using Desmos, and it appears to grow very slowly. I'm not sure if it actually does converge though, as it's hard to apply any of the tests to this monster of a generating function:

[image]

Any ideas/insights?

Answer (score 3):

I can't add a comment but $C_n$  > 1/n.

Comment: Feel like this is pretty much an answer, anyway.